# Export mysql to ASCII in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I would like to save database schema using `describe` function to visualise the tables for others in a team, in mysql terminal you can use `describe tablename` which would output in a table all in text which I would simply pipe to a text file.

In this current environment I do not have access to mysql terminal but only through phpMyAdmin, is there a way I can get a table view using text in phpMyAdmin? I know phpMyAdmin has its own print view but this is not what I want, I want just plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice "table as text" rendering that the mysql console is doing is unique to that software.

It is basically how mysql console renders any result set that you get from your query.

PhpMyAdmin will render all the results sets in a HTML table. As far as I know they do not emulate the text output because they have no reason to.

If you are able to run a PHP script on that machine you could use that to render the result set as text and display it in a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Phpmyadmin has an export function.

If you export only the structure of your database, but not the data, and you export it to SQL format, you will get a text file with your database's DDL nicely formatted.

That should help you document the database for your team.